# Recover LVM without boot HDD

Tags: data-recovery, lvm

I have scoured the 'net for an answer and am here as a last resort;
I have a "NAS" running Ubuntu Server. It boots from a 250G HDD and there are 4 X 1T HDDs formatted as LVM.

The boot HDD crashed and there is no backup

The LVM has a backup but is a few days out of date. Ideally I'd like to recover the LVM HDDs.

Is there a relatively simple way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you know where the logical volumes begin/end you should be fine. The easier method to know that is through the lvm backup files you have. It doesn't really matter that they're a few days old, as long as the lvm-partitioning didn't change since then. On the other hand, if you've modified the partitioning then you've to grep search the devices for this information. This is slightly more challenging but not still feasible.

Have a look at what [this guy did](http://blog.adamsbros.org/2009/05/30/recover-lvm-volume-groups-and-logical-volumes-without-backups/).

[Or this other one](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/02/how-to-recover-lvm-partition-on-damaged.html)

In a nutshell the usual recovery strategy for lvm corrupted systems seems to be this:

1. find where the logical volume/s you want to recover begins/ends
2. dd the blocks in this sector in a new file
3. Possibily manipulate the header so that it works (someone zeroed the
   lvm header), then mount the file as ext3/4 block device.
4. Recover files